# Nodejs socket.io is emitting message to client as number of clients connected

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I made a nodejs server wich uses socket.io to establish communication with web client, the server is sending sockets to specific client, the issue is if I have 5 clients connected to the server, the client will receive the sent message 5 times!

here is my code :

```
var fs = require('fs'),
         http = require('http'),
         io  = require('socket.io'),
         qs = require('querystring');
         sys = require ('util'),
         url = require('url');


var message, AndroidID;

//Traitement Serveur nodejs
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

        if(req.method=='POST') {
            var body = '';
            req.on('data', function (data) {
              body += data;
            });

            req.on('end',function(){
                server.emit('sendingData', body);
                console.log("Body : " + body);
            });

            res.write("success");
            res.end();
        } else {
          res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
          res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html'));
        }


}).listen(8080, function() {
   console.log('Listening at: http://localhost:8080');
});

var socket = io.listen(server);
var clients = {};
var compteur = 0;
// Traitement socket.io

socket.on('connection', function (client) {
    clients[compteur] = client;
    client.emit('firstConnection', client.id, compteur);
    console.log('clients : ', clients);
    compteur += 1;

    client.on('message', function (msg) {
        console.log('Message Received: ', msg);
        client.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
    });

    server.on('sendingData', function(data){
      message = data.substring(8, data.lastIndexOf('&'));
      androidID = data.substr(-1);

      console.log('[+] Sending Data : ', message ,' TO : ',  parseInt(androidID));

      clients[parseInt(androidID)].emit('androidmsg', message);
    });

});
```

The nodejs server is receiving data from a php HTTPClient

Comment: Which message is being replicated.

Comment: This one

`server.on('sendingData', function(data){
      message = data.substring(8, data.lastIndexOf('&'));
      androidID = data.substr(-1);

      console.log('[+] Sending Data : ', message ,' TO : ',  parseInt(androidID));

      clients[parseInt(androidID)].emit('androidmsg', message);
    });`

Comment: You are trying to use http server like socket.io . You do `server.emit('sendingData', body);` for every POST request. And you process it per each connected user times each sendingData recieved to server. Try to move `server.on('sendingData', function(data)` out of `socket.on('connection', function (client)`

Answer (score 2):

You should put `server.on('sendingData', function(data){...});` outside `socket.on('connection', function (client){...});`. This is because the `sendingData` event is for http server and not socket.io server.

Putting it inside `socket.io` connection handler makes it repeatedly execute for each connected client to socket.io server